# Universal App network connection status

Tags: c#, asp.net, xaml, asp.net-web-api, win-universal-app

I am trying to build an universal app in win8 and one of the features is to display the connection status. The status is displayed as a button which goes 'Green' if active and 'Red' if inactive.

here is the network detection code:

```
        public class InternetConnectionChangedEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public InternetConnectionChangedEventArgs(bool isConnected)
    {
        this.isConnected = isConnected;
    }
    private bool isConnected;

    public bool IsConnected
    {
        get { return isConnected; }
    }
}

public static class Network
{
    public static event EventHandler<InternetConnectionChangedEventArgs> 
        InternetConnectionChanged;

    static Network()
    {
        NetworkInformation.NetworkStatusChanged += (s) =>
        {
            if (InternetConnectionChanged != null)
            {
                var arg = new InternetConnectionChangedEventArgs(IsConnected);
                InternetConnectionChanged(null, arg);
            }
        };
    }

    public static bool IsConnected
    {
        get
        {
            var profile = NetworkInformation.GetInternetConnectionProfile();
            var isConnected = (profile != null
                && profile.GetNetworkConnectivityLevel() == 
                NetworkConnectivityLevel.InternetAccess);
            return isConnected;
        }
    }
}
```

so at the end i Call the function to set the color of the button, , but however the system throws an exception stating that the "Application is using a thread marshalled for a different thread"

Here is the code in the Main() constructor.

The app throws an exception once the network cable is pulled off..

```
    Network.InternetConnectionChanged +=async(s,e)=>
            {
                await Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
                {
                    isInternetON=e.IsConnected;
                });

                SetConnectionStaus(isInternetON);


            };
```

MY GUESS IS THAT I'M CALLING ONE THREAD FROM AN ANOTHER WHILE UPDATING THE COLOR OF THE BUTTON.....KINDLY HELP!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this snippet to update UI property from non-UI threat:

```
await Windows.ApplicationModel.Core.CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
{
//Do thing / change value here
});
```